# bmf kgf dc yufy ckd yb crysn

Tags: cipher

A friend told me to try to decrypt this as a fun puzzle but won’t tell me the answer:

> `bmf kgf dc yufy ckd yb crysn`

He gave me this (which I think is the key or at least related to it):

- `shark`
- `C`
- `beta`
- `256`
- `orioncaa`
- `lu ca`
- `include`

He also told me to use google search where I could input things to decrypt the message, but I am stuck with no clue.

Comment: I think you're looking for https://cryptii.com/

Comment: I tried that, there's nothing related.

Comment: When you go to choose the "MODEL" on https://cryptii.com/ one of the options is "Enigma M4 Shark", is that correct?

Comment: @theooofsof2023 I've managed to figure out some of the clues, hopefully this helps. On cryptii.com, you need to decode the cipher text using the Enigma Machine, with model `Enigma M4 "Shark"`, reflector `UKW C thin`, Rotor 1 `Beta`, and from `lu ca` and `include`, it can be determined that you need to use a plugboard `lu ca` and include foreign characters. Although that's all I've figured out so far. Edit: nvm,you also need Rotor 2 set to `II`, Rotor 3 set to `V`, and Rotor 4 set to `VI` (that's how `256` comes into play)

Comment: Might I suggest putting the cypher and clues in a code block (using ` symbols) for formatting purposes? The edits were too small for me to make.

Comment: @CrSb0001 `orioncaa` might stand for the position and ring. When choosing the position and ring for each rotor, there's a letter next to the number. The amount of letters in `orioncaa` corresponds with the amount positions + rings (4 each). Edit: nvm, didn't work. It might also be that you need to use the letters in a different order, than I used them

Comment: @WOWOW Okay then I might have solved it. I'll post an answer.

Comment: @CrSb0001 it didn't work

Comment: @WOWOW nvm then

Comment: @CrSb0001 It might be in a different order, but that's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: @WOWOW I also thought of Position: `ORIO` Ring: `NCAA` but that didn't work either, so either something's wrong with the positions/rings or it's with the rotors where something is wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152164/discussion-between-crsb0001-and-wowow).

Comment: @theooofsof2023 Are you sure every info is correct?

Answer (score 4):

It's most likely undecodable (due to undercluing), but I would like to give the benefit of the doubt to OP and say that they transcribed the hints and cipher correctly. (so not OP's fault)

Here's how:

We know that from the hints, the following are correct:

> 1. Cipher: Enigma Machine
> 2. Reflector: UKW C Thin
> 3. Model: Enigma M4 "Shark"
> 4. Rotor 1: Beta
> 5. Rotor 2-4: II, V, VI
> 6. Plugboard: `lu ca`

Note that it doesn't matter whether foreign characters are included or not, since that would only matter if there were characters outside of the Ascii value range of 97-122. Also, characters with an Ascii value of 65-90 would only get changed to their lowercase variants, so if the solution has to do with capitalized letters, then that is very bad.

---

Now, here is the only reason one is able to tell why rotors 2-4 were `II`, `V` and `VI` in the first place, which was something that was really bugging us in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/152164):

> Well, what if instead three letters from `ORIONCAA` had to be the rotors? To see why we couldn't do that, let's convert the letters to Roman Numerals:
> `XV XVIII IX XV XIV III I I`

> There's a problem here: If `256` was supposed to clue to either the positions or rings, then what's the point of the `ORIONCAA`? We can't have `ORI`->`XV XVIII IX` be the rotors, since their Roman Numeral values fall outside the allowed rotor selection range of `I` through `VIII`.

> Then there is the problem of what the solution was even supposed to look like, which led to a probably unintended red herring in the puzzle. As @WOWOW [mentioned in chat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nl6MO.png):
> ...although we quickly ran into a problem with that, [as we quickly found out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ro5Ph.png). So now we knew that yes, deciphering using the Enigma Machine is the way to go.

However, assuming that everything is correct and the only problem is with the positions/rings, why isn't it solvable? Here's why:

```
Note: Position/Ring are from top -> bottom

Ciphertext: bmf kgf dc yufy ckd yb crsyn

+--------+----+----------------------------+
|Position|Ring|      Output (Decoding)     |
+--------+----+----------------------------+
|  ORIO  |NCAA|xsy ren ft gqdx mpz qc zoxus|
+--------+----+----------------------------+
|  OINC  |ROCA|tzb zsg sq osql bpa an hcbdq|
+--------+----+----------------------------+

+--------+----+----------------------------+
|Position|Ring|      Output (Encoding)     |
+--------+----+----------------------------+
|  ORIO  |NCAA|xsy ren ft gqdx mpz qc zoxus|
+--------+----+----------------------------+
|  OINC  |ROCA|tzb zsg sq osql bpa an hcbdq|
+--------+----+----------------------------+
```

So as we can see, both encoding and decoding the ciphertext with our current setting gives the same result.

Now, here's some quick math:

> Assuming everything but the positions/rings are correct, then there is a $\frac1{26^8}$ or a 208827064576 to 1 chance of randomly guessing all 8 positions/rings (4 positions and 4 rings) correctly first try.
> Assuming we know that `ORIONCAA` is correct, but not necessarily in that order, that brings it down to searching through all 10080 possible combinations (or $\frac{8!}{2!2!}=\frac{8!}{(2!)^2}$) of arrangements of the letters in `ORIONCAA`.
> If it is to be fully together, then we have a total of 8 possible combinations to use.

However, I would like to assume best intentions and say that either the ciphertext is incorrect or that it was underclued, therefore making the cipher impossible to decode.